# How do I figure out which kind of mapping of the @RequestMapping annotation was chosen in a controller method?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Let's suppose that one controller has a method where mapping multiple requests to the same method may be necessary. The question is: In the body of the method, how do I know which kind of mapping the user has requested.

This is what I want to achieve but don't know how:

```
@Controller
public class TopicController {
    
    @GetMapping(value={"/mapping_1", "/mapping_2"})
    public String my_topics(...) {
        if (mappingValue == "/mapping_1") {
            // do something.
        }
        else if (mappingValue == "/mapping_2") {
            // do something else.
        }
        
        return "template";
    }
```

**EDIT**: Okay I got it. What I did is I added "HttpServletRequest request" as a argument of the method and called the request.getRequestURI() function to get the URI I needed.

I got something like this.

```
@Controller
public class TopicController {
    
    @GetMapping(value={"/mapping_1", "/mapping_2"})
    public String my_topics(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.getRequestURI().equals("/mapping_1")) {
            // do something.
        }
        else if (request.getRequestURI().equals("/mapping_2")) {
            // do something else.
        }
        
        return "template";
    }
}
```

Thank you all who tried to help me! Y'all gave me the idea to solive my question.

Comment: Did you try getting HttpRequest object and reading URL from it?

Comment: Deepak Kumar, I'm not familiar with getting HttpRequest object yet. Currently, I'm trying to find any kind of information of that. Anyway, I would be glad if you could explain me about it.

Comment: Just add the HttpRequest as an argument of the method. And after that, you can call an HttpRequest method to get the URL.

Comment: if you have entirely different things to do ,why not create separate rest end points ? I don't think this is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a if based on the path, this is better to do two method, else you can make a private method for common code with 2 methods to map the path.

**EDIT:** UriComponentsBuilder as parameter

Comment: Yes, I could make a private method for common code but I'm wondering if there's any annotation or some like that to do it rignt in the same method.

Comment: ok you can use UriComponentsBuilder as method argument, it will be injected with URL details

Answer (score 0):

I see you found the solution but I also give another option:

```
@Controller
public class TopicController {
    
    @GetMapping(value={"/mapping_1", "/mapping_2"})
    public String my_topics(HttpServletRequest request) {

        if (request.getRequestURL().toString().endsWith("/mapping_1")) {
            // do something.
        }
        else if (request.getRequestURL().toString().endsWith("/mapping_2")) {
            // do something else.
        }
        
        return "template";
    }
```